# undefined method `first_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anyone shed light on this for me?

undefined method `first_name' for #

Here is the show.html

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div id="container">
<p>
  <b>First name:</b>
  <%= @artist.firstname %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Second name:</b>
  <%= @artist.surname %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>About:</b>
  <%= @artist.about %>
</p>
<div id="comments">

  <h2>Comments</h2>

<%= render :partial => "shared/comment", :collection => @artist.comments%>

</div
</div>

<%= render :partial => "image", :collection => @artist.images %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_artist_path(@artist) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', artists_path %>
<%= link_to 'show', images_path %>
```

Here is the partial

```
 <div class="comment">



     <p>


      <span class="commentator"><%= comment.commentator.display_name %> 

    say's</span>


      <%= comment.comment %>


      </p>



    </div
```

Here is the friend view

```
class Friends < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :firstname, :surname
    has_many :comments, :as => :commentator, :class_name =>"Commentable"
    def display_name
    "#{self.firstname} #{self.surname}"
    end


end
```

This is the friends controller

```
class FriendsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /friends
  # GET /friends.xml
  def index
    @friends = Friend.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @friends }
    end
  end

  # GET /friends/1
  # GET /friends/1.xml
  def show
    @friend = Friend.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @friend }
    end
  end

  # GET /friends/new
  # GET /friends/new.xml
  def new
    @friend = Friend.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @friend }
    end
  end

  # GET /friends/1/edit
  def edit
    @friend = Friend.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /friends
  # POST /friends.xml
  def create
    @friend = Friend.new(params[:friend])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @friend.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@friend, :notice => 'Friend was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @friend, :status => :created, :location => @friend }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @friend.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /friends/1
  # PUT /friends/1.xml
  def update
    @friend = Friend.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @friend.update_attributes(params[:friend])
        format.html { redirect_to(@friend, :notice => 'Friend was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @friend.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /friends/1
  # DELETE /friends/1.xml
  def destroy
    @friend = Friend.find(params[:id])
    @friend.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(friends_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to make it so a friend can leave a comment on an artists page but I keep getting the above error.

I am very new to Ruby so I apologise if I have left anything out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, rails will look at the database to figure out what fields are on a model. So make sure your migrations have been run, and that first_name exists on the db table.

Also, Friends is plural. In rails, your table is plural (friends), your model is singular (Friend), and your controller is plural (FriendsController). It is best not to go against this convention. Try renaming the model and see what happens

Comment: t.string :firstname
t.string :surname

Comment: thats your problem, replace first_name with firstname in your ruby code, and it should work

Comment: I've updated my code and edited it above so you can see but I am still getting the same error.

undefined method `firstname' for #

Comment: Also you need to change `self.last_name` to `self.surname` because that is going to break as well - whatever you use for naming in your database migrations is what you need to use in your Ruby code.

Comment: that has been edited, my new code is above.

Thanks for the help you are giving me.

Comment: how about you try stopping your server, running rake db:migrate, and starting again, just to double check everything is the way it is supposed to be?

Comment: Still no luck :/ I have been stuck on this for two days not. Doing my head in haha.

Comment: Just saw another problem, Friends is plural. In rails, your table is plural (friends), your model is singular (Friend), and your controller is plural (FriendsController). It is best not to go against this convention. Try renaming the model and see what happens

Comment: I have two models for some reason. 1 Called friend.rb and one called friends.rb I will destroy friends.rb

Comment: Still doesn't work, I have posted my FriendsController above, do I need to change anything in my routes.rb

Comment: NoMethodError in Artists#show

Showing /home/scm-studs/k0084447/The_Connected_Artist/app/views/artists/show.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `firstname' for #<Artist:0x7f040f8dcb50>

Extracted source (around line #5):

2: <div id="container">
3: <p>
4:   <b>First name:</b>
5:   <%= @artist.firstname %>
6: </p>
7: 
8: <p>

Comment: What is interesting here is that you are getting Artist:0x7f040f8dcb50. Artist is the name of the class, and 0x7f040f8dcb50 is the address in memory. But in the controller you aren't setting \@artist, you are setting \@friend. Are you sure you are hitting the controller/view that you think you are hitting?

Comment: (the \@ is because stackoverflow is a bit too eager with its twitter like reply feature)

Comment: Maybe I'm not, I just want to be able to display the comments I have in my database onto the artist page and I'm not sure how I go about this. I think I have messed up somewhere down the line.

Comment: Where does Friend and FriendsController factor into things? Based on what you are showing, I would expect that to be app/views/artists/show.html.erb, which would have the app/controllers/artists_controller.rb, and app/models/artist.rb files that are being used to render it

Answer (score 0):

You need line 2 of the `Friend` class to be `attr_accessible :firstname, :surname` so your views have access to the those variables.

Comment: Where does this need to be placed?

Comment: line 2 of the `Friend` class, above your `has_many` declaration

Comment: It looks like `Friend` is a subclass of `Commentator` - ensure that `Commentator` class also has `attr_accessible` for first and last name.

Comment: attr_accessor is probably what you are talking about (attr_accessible is about whitelisting for mass assignment), but I think his first_name/last_name is supposed to come from the db, so attr_accessor won't solve the problem

Comment: @MattBriggs my assumption was that at somepoint the `Commentator` needs to have `first_name` and `last_name` assigned so he's going to need that anyway and yeah at the `Friend` class if it's solely used to view `Commentator` names then you could only need to use `attr_accessor`.

Comment: Not having any luck whatsoever

Comment: @LawrenceSmith post your `Commentator` class

Answer (score 0):

This error related to database that first_name don't exist in your db.Run migration carefully.

Comment: I have changed it to firstname rather than first_name and I am still receiving the same error.